# Python Pandas - If statement checking a True False Boolean Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas df with a column of True False values.  I am trying to construct an if statement that tests that column, but am not getting the desired result.  I think I am using the .bool method incorrectly.  The basic idea is to check if the value of the current row Col1is True, and if any of the three prior rows Col1 was False, return True in Col2

```
from pandas import DataFrame
 
names = {'col1': [False, False, False, False, False, True, True, 
     True, False, False]}
df = DataFrame(names, columns =['col1'])

if df.col1.bool == True:
   if df.col1.shift(1).bool == False:
    df['col2'] = True
  elif df.col1.shift(2).bool == False:
    df['col2'] = True
  elif df.col1.shift(3).bool == False:
    df['col2'] = True
  else:
    df['col2'] = False

df
```

Comment: can you share the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it, using np.where and pd.rolling and by taking the sum of boolean values, which would be less than 3 unless all previous three values are true
IIUC, the previous three, excluding the current row

```
df['col2']=np.where((df['col1'].shift(1).rolling(3).sum()<3) &(df['col1']==True),
                    True,
                    False)
df
```

```
    col1    col2
0   False   False
1   False   False
2   False   False
3   False   False
4   False   False
5   True    True
6   True    True
7   True    True
8   False   False
9   False   False
```

Comment: Thank you.  The solution works, but I am confused as to the True, False in the where method.  It seems like it should be True, True.  What am I missing.

Comment: True for Col2 when condition in where is met else false.

Answer (score 1):

The lines `df['col2'] = True` and `df['col2'] = False` set the whole column to True and False, respectively. Since you want element-wise operations, you need to use the overloaded bitwise operations `&` (for AND) and `|` (for OR).

Your new column should be true when the current value of `col1` is True AND at least one of the previous 3 values are False, which could be encoded as:

```
df['col2'] = df.col1 & (
    (df.col1.shift(1) == False) |
    (df.col1.shift(2) == False) |
    (df.col1.shift(3) == False)
)
```

Be careful with the operator precedence when using the bitwise operations as they have lower priority than the comparison operators. This can often lead to subtle bugs producing the wrong results but do not cause errors. I advise to use extra parenthesis in these expressions.

Comment: Thank you. I like this solution, but I do have an additional question.  What is it about the first reference to df.col1 that defaults it to True (just before the &)?  How would I write this if I wanted if to perform the additional tests only when col1 was False?

Comment: `df.col1` is a `Series` of boolean values that were initialized when constructing the `DataFrame`. Since each value already is `True` or `False` you do need to compare with `True`. That is, `x == True` is equivalent to `x` for boolean values. If you wanted the inverse, i.e. when only col1 was `False`, you could use `df.col1 == False` or the element-wise negation operator `~`, eg: `~df.col1`. Also note, if the column is not boolean values and needs to be converted to bools then you should use the `df.col1.bool` as in the question.

Comment: Thank you for the through explanation.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pandas import DataFrame

names = {'col1': [False, False, False, False, False, True, True, 
 True, False, False]}
df = DataFrame(names, columns =['col1'])
df['col2'] = False
df['col2'][df['col1']==False] = True
df['col2'][df['col1'].shift(1)==False] = True
df['col2'][df['col1'].shift(2)==False] = True
df['col2'][df['col1'].shift(3)==False] = True

df
```

or if you want to compact it a bit

```
from pandas import DataFrame

names = {'col1': [False, False, False, False, True, True, True, 
 True, False, False]}
df = DataFrame(names, columns =['col1'])
df['col2'] = False
df['col2'][(df['col1']==False) | (df['col1'].shift(1)==False) | (df['col1'].shift(2)==False) | (df['col1'].shift(3)==False)] = True
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  This did not produce the desired result when I tested it.